# Trouble Converting string [] to int []

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, type-conversion

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Test_Arrays_and_Files
{  
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tFile = @"C:\Programming\GLO\DC\dcw.txt";
            string read = File.ReadAllText(tFile);
            string[] test = read.Split(',');
            int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(test, int.Parse);
            Console.WriteLine(ints[0]);                  
        }        
    }
}
```

**Input Data:**

Text File Contents:(1 value per line,)

```
35,
35,
40,
40,
40,
```

getting System.FormatException: Input string was not in correct format
please help and sorry for bad post I'm new here

Comment: What are the contents of dcw.txt?

Comment: Hi I'm sorry this post is so shit i was having errors getting the forum to accept my question. I'm aware of similar questions being posted and answered here but those solutions have not worked for me yet. (Probably something I'm doing wrong)

So I've been trying to convert string[] test into an int[], i would like all the indexes to line up properly but I'm getting a format issue with input string every time I try to run the program. I've tried s=> int.Parse (format issue) and linq but can get .Select to work

Comment: 35, 35, 40, 40, 40, (Each value on a different line)

Comment: Suggest you remove the line endings from the string containing the file contents before you do the Split. Also, when doing the Split, I believe there's an option to remove whitespace and empty entries.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your code,

1. Your string is ending with `,` which is creating empty record after the split. This is the reason you are getting the error.
2. Your delimiter could be `$",{Environment.NewLine}"` not only `','`.

So to convert given `string` to `int` array, first [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0) the input string by `,` and then split by `$",{Environment.NewLine}"`.

Like,

```
using System.Linq;
...
var result = str.Trim(',') //Remove leading and trailing comma(s), You can use `TrimEnd()` as well
      .Split($",{Environment.NewLine}", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)   //Split by given delimiter.
      .Select(int.Parse)
      .ToArray();    //Convert string[] to int[]
```

[Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WW24Ks)

Comment: Note that making change  2) would actively *cause* a problem in certain scenarios like parsing a file created in Windows, on Linux

Comment: @CaiusJard, If I am not wrong you are pointing `Environment.NewLine` might create issue  on different OS. Then we can split by only `,` with removing empty entries. I will update my answer soon and will inform once it is done

Comment: I'd like to thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction. The other users answer fixed my problem but feel free to post your updated answer if desired. I am very new to this so I'm always open to different perspectives. Thanks again for taking the time to do this! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting it because the file has a comma at the end, which means Split ends up churning out an empty string in the very last position. int.Parse will choke on the empty string

Plenty of ways you could solve it, one is to tell Split not to return you empties, by changing the split line of your code to:

```
string[] test = read.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You could instead trim the comma off the end, but using the above approach would mean your parsing would survive a blank line in the middle of the file too so overall it's more robust

Generally when parsing strings it's more robust to use TryParse than Parse. TryParse takes in the number variable to set the result to and returns you a Boolean telling if the parsing succeeded

```
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(test, GetIntOrMinusOne);


//put a method helper
private int GetIntOrMinusOne(string s){
  if(int.TryParse(s, out var t)
    return t;
  return -1;
}
```

For this we need to get a bit more involved with the `ConvertAll` call. Instead of telling ConvertAll to call a "method that converts a string to an int" like `int.Parse`, we need to write our own mini method that tries to parse and if it fails return something like -1, then nominate *that* as the method to call to do the conversion, not int.Parse

It's important to note that this would introduce -1 into the resulting `int[]` array wherever there was bad data in the string array.. In your later processing you would then do some check to avoid them (such as skipping them)

You can shorten that code above by turning the method into a lambda:

```
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(test, s => int.TryParse(s, out var t) ? t : -1);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                a lambda; "just the important parts of a method"
```

But I'm not sure that you'll have come across lambdas yet, judging by the style of the rest of the code

Comment: Thank you!! The method helper you provided worked out well for me!  And you're right about the style. I only started trying to learn coding less than a week ago. I must admit i dont fully understand whats going on with the code but I will take the time to disect it. I really appreciate you putting in the time to answer this. I will do my best to not post annoying questions often and do my own research before relying on others for help. Again, Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to dissect is to click on the first line, press F9 so it goes red and run the program. When the yellow bar stops press f10 to move one step at a time d see mx use your mouse o point at variable names to see their current value